# Having issues aligning text next to an image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

My first time posting and am looking for some help. I am currently taking an assessment and am stumped on the last part. I am making a picture card with an image above and a circle image to the side as well as some text next to the circle image and below **this is what it looks like:** https://i.gyazo.com/547948a01bd8f045e6a1b90bd79e113a.png

**this is how it needs to look:**

https://i.gyazo.com/9426e3f060cdd540581f12da474fc8ca.png

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>App Academy HTML/CSS Assessment</title>
  <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="card">
  <img src="./images/desert.jpg" alt="desert" class="desert__img">
  <img src="./images/person-avatar.jpg" alt="avatar" class="avatar__img">
  <div class="title__text">
    <h4>Title goes here</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="secondary__text">
    <p>Secondary text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="body__text">Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
   @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    form {
        display: grid;
        position: relative;
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    form {
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

}


/*Style for picture card*/


.card {
   /* text-align: center; */
    width: 344px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.desert__img {
    width: 344px;
    height: 194px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.avatar__img {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    justify-self: start;
    padding: 10px;
}

.body__text {
    padding: 16px;
}

div h4 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: top;
}


div p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    justify-self: center;
}
```

Any help would be awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>App Academy HTML/CSS Assessment</title>
        <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="card">
            <img src="./images/desert.jpg" alt="desert" class="desert__img"> 
            <div class="container1">
                <img src="./images/person-avatar.jpg" alt="avatar" class="avatar__img">
                <div class="container2">
                    <div><h4>Title goes here</h4></div>
                    <div><p>Secondary text</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="body__text">Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here we used 2 containers, one for row and one for column elements. You can achieve this easily and more effectively with HTML tables.
Next here is the css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    form {
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

}


/*Style for picture card*/


.card {
   /* text-align: center; */
   border-radius: 25px;
    width: 344px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.desert__img {
    width: 344px;
    height: 194px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.avatar__img {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    justify-self: start;
    padding: 10px;
}

.body__text {
    padding: 16px;
}

.container1{
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.container2{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

/* ************These styles are junk************ */
/* *********Better to use classes n ids********* */
div h4 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: top;
}


div p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    justify-self: center;
}
/* ************These styles are junk************ */
```

Here I added `border-radius` property to the card to make its corner round. Use `border-top-left-radius`, `border-top-right-radius` with image to make its top borders round which gives card a neat look. It is important to give height n width to image, thus I added `height` property to avatar pic. Lastly, both container classes are set to contain rows and column without wrapping respectively, using `flex-flow` property. Hope it will help you. Peace.

Comment: This helped a ton. Still new to this, so trying to learn the best way to use flex and CSS grid when possible. Thank you!~

Answer (score 0):

Add a float property to the .avatar_img class

```
.avatar_img {
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `title__text` and `secondary__text` inside `div`,

and then wrap `avatar__img` and title inside flexbox `div`.

```
  <div class="card-info">
    <img src="./images/person-avatar.jpg" alt="avatar" class="avatar__img">
    <div class="card-info-title">
      <div class="title__text">
        <h4>Title goes here</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="secondary__text">
        <p>Secondary text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.card-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.secondary__text > p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's CodePen link https://codepen.io/azhkuro/pen/WNrXxpd. Hope it helps you